# App.config para acessar um banco SQL Server?

Tags: c#

Como posso ajustar este `app.config` pra acessar meu banco SQL Server?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IServidor" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:2666/Servidor.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IServidor" contract="ServidorReference.IServidor"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IServidor" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode add uma ***ConnectionString***.
Logo após a tag ***startup*** em seu ***App.config*** você pode add:

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConexaoSQLSERVER" 
             connectionString="Data Source=EnderecoServer; 
                               Initial Catalog=NomedaDB; 
                               Integrated Security=True;" 
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

Caso deseje usar uma LocalDB e queira atacar um banco em diretório,
sua connectionString ficar assim:

```
Server=.\\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Caminho até a DB\\MinhaDB.mdf;Database=NomedaDB;
Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

Para atacar a DB na pasta do projeto:

```
Server=.\\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DiretoriodoProjeto|suadb.mdf;Database=NomedaDB;
Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

Antes de começar a construção da conexão atente-se para na esquecer de adicionar a referência que manipula o App.config.

[image: Add referências System.Configuration]

[image: Add referências System.Configuration]

No projeto crie uma classe separada para manipular a conexão:
[image: Construção da Classe]

Um exemplo do uso da ConexaoDB:
[image: Ultilizacão da ConexaoDB]

Answer (score 0):

Para acessar o seu *SQL Server*, seu app.config tem que ter as strings de conexão

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="NomeDaStringDeConexao" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress; Initial Catalog=SeuBanco;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: mas é isso que nao sei como fazer é modificar !

Comment: esse app.config??????

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo completo do app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>    
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlServerConnString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Para retornar a string do app.config utilize:

```
var connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlServerConnString"].ConnectionString;
```

Esses exemplo eu extraí de um repositório meu do GitHub, você pode conferir lá como está feito.

https://github.com/thiagoloureiro/Dapper_ComplexObjects/